# who should own the web root of my server?

Tags: ubuntu, security, nginx, permissions, php-fpm

I read a book about security in web servers and I found this:

> If your web server has the ability to write to the ﬁles in your
>   WordPress directories, then the automatic upgrade functionality works.
>   If not,WordPress prompts for your FTP credentials to update the ﬁles
>   for you. Both of these situations concern us. In general, **your web
>   user should not have write permissions to your entire web root**. This
>   is just asking for trouble, especially on a shared hosting platform;
>   realizing, of course, that certain directories such as the uploads
>   folder must be writable by the web user in order to function.

*Professional Wordpress by Hal Stern*

What I want to ask is who is the web user of my server? I'm using Nginx and PHP5-FPM. The web root folder of my server is owned by raymond:raymond. Nginx is running as nginx:nginx and PHP5-FPM's **listen.owner** is set to **raymond** and **listen.group** is also set to **raymond**

The web root directory permissions is drwxr-x-r-x, my public_html is also set like that.

So how can I know if I'm in trouble with this setup?

BTW, I'm using Linode for my host! I'm not in a shared hosting environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've answered your own question.

The "web user" refers to the identity of the user running nginx - in this case, uid=nginx, gid=nginx.

As log as this user does not own or have write access to files that should not be modifiable (such as the abovementioned wordpress config), you're fine.

EDIT: Unless PHP5-FPM is started as a separate process which runs as root, it cannot excercise more  permissions than those present on the web server.

Comment: ok i now understand. i was very confused a while ago because i don't know who's the web user. i thought nginx is the server user. so it really gets very confusing. thank you for clarifying my confusion.